# Cannot write in Greek

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.04, which I'm unfamiliar with. I think the language package is installed correctly but there is no layout switching by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination. Tried to look for a solution. Have not found any instructions that work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if that is what you want. But if you want to change your keyboard layout using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> then you could go about it this way:

[image: Shortcut to switch keyboard layout]

Go to "Keyboard Preferences" either using the keyboard indicator or dash. Than select the "Layout" pane. There click "Options" which will open the "Keyboard Layout Options". Under "Key(s) to change layout" you can check the box next to your desired shortcut.

I think this is ***outdated***, but maybe worth a tray:

```
# In /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier      "Keyboard"
    Option          "XkbModel"      "pc105"
    Option          "XkbLayout"     "us,de" # de stand for german, replace this with your layout!
    Option          "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle,lv3:ralt_switch"
EndSection
```

---

**Edit:**
As stated in the comments: I didn't have a Greek keyboard layout in his layout list and had to add it like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, already did that, didn't work. Perhaps there's a problem with my language installation? Do I have to log out in order to take effect?

Comment: That's very odd. And no, typically it should work without restart. You could try `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` also I edited my answer a litte.

Comment: problem solved! I just have read more carefully ubuntu help documentation instructions, just had to ADD a greek layout for my keyboard. Sorry for wasting your time :( And Thanks of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, even when I added the greek language. All it needed finally was a computer restart.